# Call a method in model in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I've created a model called Hangman. Inside a controller I'm inserting a row in the database like this

```
$hangman = new Hangman();
$hangman->word = 'exampleWord';
$hangman->lives = 3;
$hangman->save();
```

So far so good.

I've got two questions:

1) Is it best practice to keep inserting things in the controller?

I assume NO, so I created this method in the model, which I think would be cleaner to call from the controller

```
public function insert($word, $lives)
{
    $hangman = new Hangman();
    $hangman->word = $word;
    $hangman->lives = $lives;
    $hangman->save();

    return $hangman;
}
```

So, my real question (assuming question 1 is NO) is:

2) How would I call this method from the controller?

This doesn't work

```
 \App\Hangman::insert('exampleword', 4);
```

Namespaces are correct.

I know it's very basic, thanks guys

Comment: There's no problem to have that code in Controller. The model functions are encapsulated, so you can have that code in controller. Have a look at Laravel Guide: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#basic-inserts

Comment: @JavierNúñez I know I can have it, it's just I don't want to have 4 or 5 lines if I can have just one line with the insert call. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody can answer your first question properly, as it's a matter of personal preference and people have various opinions. Putting it in the model may be a good idea, as might putting it in a repository. In the right application, having it in a controller might be worth it, whereas other systems may favour yet other solutions.

As for your second question: since you're in the Hangman model, you should make the self-referential call static, and also the method itself.

```
public static function insert($word, $lives)
{
    $hangman = new static;
    $hangman->word = $word;
    $hangman->lives = $lives;
    $hangman->save();

    return $hangman;
}
```

And that should be enough. You could also save yourself a few lines:

```
public static function insert($word, $lives)
{
    return static::create(compact('word', 'lives'));
}
```

Comment: Wow! That is an elegant solution! Yes, you're right about the first question, it's just I don't feel it's clean to have 4 or 5 lines in the controller when you can have just one.

Comment: That is definitely a fair concern. I believe Jeffrey Way has some videos on the subject over at Laracasts.com, but it's been quite a while so I'm not sure which they would be.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a method with :: double colons unless the method is static. Therefore you should change your method to a static method.

```
public static function insert($word, $lives)
{
   // logic
}
```

You are actually doing this the wrong way. The insert method has to be in the Controller, not inside the model. Move your insert method to Controller and use it. Creating an instance of the Model inside the Controller is the right way to do it.

Right now, you are trying to create an instance of a class inside the same class (Hangman inside Hangman). That's not the right way to do it in MVC architecture.